# Understanding platform targets/references/CSC warnings

Tags: c#, .net, platform

My solution structure is as follows:

Main GUI project **(A)** -> which uses project with API logic **(B)** -> which uses external API DLL **(C)**.

The external API DLL **(C)** is built for x86, which displays a CSC warning recommending that I should switch the platform target of **(B)** to x86 too or I might get runtime errors.

If I do that, I get another CSC warning, that the processor architecture of **(B)** is different than **(A)**, so I should switch **(A)** to x86 too.

I guess I could do that too, but lately I've installed VS2022 which is x64, and then **(A)** fails to display forms in Designer because of the different architecture. Is there any workaround to all of this? Should I just ignore all these warnings and set **(A)** and **(B)** to AnyCPU?

Comment: You'll need to find out why that library was built to target x86.  If it is just a mistake then [use this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool).

Comment: @HansPassant I believe that the external API is cross-platform compatible, and used by them also in ASP.NET projects and others. It is also a COM Assembly, if that matters somehow. However, my solution will not be run in such environments, it's targetted towards Windows 10/11 and some Windows Server editions. So I think I should be safe to set AnyCPU on my projects, despite their x86 targetting.